# Tooltip on Leaflet GeoJSON is in wrong place

Tags: leaflet, geojson, tooltip

I'm trying to label a shape drawn by GeoJSON data in a way that keeps the label visible even if part or most of the shape is off screen. The code I am replacing uses a marker given fixed coordinates and therefore it is easy to pan the map and lose that point and the marker.

I'm now trying a tooltip but it often appears in completely the wrong place. These screenshots show the park with a rough circle in blue, and the tooltip with a white shape around it.

[image]

[image]

The code

```
 const parkStyle = {
   stroke: '#FF0000',
   opacity: 1,
   weight: 2,
   fillOpacity: 0,
 };
 const parkLayer = L.geoJSON(park.geometry, { style: parkStyle});
 parkLayer.bindTooltip(park.name, {permanent: true, className: 'park-tooltip'});
 parkLayer.addTo(this.map);
```

The GeoJSON

```
{"type":"Feature",
            "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[174.05775,-39.20426],[173.9917,-39.228962],[173.96663,-39.25221],[173.951402,-39.29586],[173.958095,-39.32588],[173.9772,-39.3520],[174.00701,-39.37177],[174.04410,-39.38188],[174.102089,-39.378061],[174.135973,-39.36288],[174.16105,-39.33972],[174.174412,-39.311416],[174.169730,-39.26711],[174.136330,-39.22888],[174.05775,-39.20426]]]]},
            "properties":{"name":"Egmont National Park", center: [173.96481435000607,-39.1332981]}},
```

relevant CSS

```
.leaflet-touch {
  .leaflet-tooltip {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0px;
    color: #232D45;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.25px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
    margin: 0px !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: 900;
  }
  .leaflet-tooltip.park-tooltip {
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #232D45;
    font-family: Roboto, "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  }
  .leaflet-tooltip-right:before, .leaflet-tooltip-left:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code should work OK. How does `park-tooltip` style look like?

Comment: @TomazicM I've added the CSS related to this

Comment: For me it work OK (see https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/suk2xdL5/). It's hard to say why it doesn't work for you. It must be in some way connected to CSS and `leaflet-touch`. I left this out in my jsFiddle, since I have no touch test environment to try it.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @TomazicM. That jsFiddle link you sent has only the CSS though, did you paste the wrong thing?

Comment: It looks like I forgot to save after adding the JS part. It's OK now.

Comment: The fiddle works well so it must be else where in my system throwing it off. However the goal of this tooltip was to make it visible on screen if just one corner of the geojson shape was visible. The tooltip looks anchored to the middle so it acting the same as a marker at this point. Is that something Leaflet can manage?

Comment: No, there is no such built in functionality in Leaflet.

Comment: Ive got a similar problem. Im using a geojson of countries. the problem is that when a country has more than one polygon (for example, the US with alaska and their islands), the tooltip ends up in the middle of the ocean. is there any way of solving that?